# How to calculate intersection count in a given polygon within a grid

Tags: graph-theory, intersection-theory

I have the following problem:

- I have a given polygon (any shape)
- I have a grid with given size of grid cells (variable width and height)
- The grid contains the polygon (various number of cells required)

I know the following inputs:

- number of grid cells to contain the polygon (rows, columns)
- the number of required full cells and partial cells (that are fully inside or partially intersected with the polygon)
- the length of each side of the polygon
- the angle at each corner (between each side)

**I need to calculate how many intersections there are in the polygon.**

A few example by pictures (I need to know the number of the gray circles):

[image]

[image]

If you need more clarification, tell me.

Do you have any hint of what kind of formula could count the number of the intersections?

Comment: Is [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) of any help ?

Comment: @JeanMarie As I have no boundary points, I don't see how I could use the formula (I only know the container cells number, I don't even know the area (A), not to mention the boundary and inside points)

Comment: I'm not sure the information you know is enough on its own. Consider that a polygon with 2 fully covered cells, and 10 partially covered cells could have the 2 fully covered cells horizontally adjacent or diagonally adjacent (which affects # of grey circles covered).

Comment: @JustinBenfield I've updated the known inputs, maybe I can calculate the area of the polygon with those. Any idea with these?

Comment: It might still be possible to change the number of intersections without changing the figure's shape or size or number of full versus partial cells via clever rotations/translations.

Comment: @Nestor: The angles and side lengths together are definitely enough information to compute enclosed area, but see my previous comment for the issue with number of intersections.